# error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable

Tags: kubernetes

I have KUBECONFIG inside my .kube/ folder still facing this issue.

I have also tried

```
kubectl config set-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig.yml

kubectl config use-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig.yml
```

No luck! Still the same.

Comment: What is the command that shows this message? Did you tried to set the current context? See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration)

Comment: Even though I have set/use-context and trying to get pods/nodes/ns everything this shows the error.

Comment: the file should be named config, not kubeconfig.

Comment: Thanks @suren, but the config name can be anything like: `env_config.yml`

Comment: by default, it needs to be config. If you name it anything different, you have to pass the flag `--kubeconfig`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Answering my own question*

Initially, I had lost a lot of time on this error, but later I found that my kubeconfig is not having the correct context.

I tried the same steps:

```
kubectl config set-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig1.yml

kubectl config use-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig1.yml
```

or add a line with kubeconfig to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/<kubeconfig_env>.yml
```

Also, if you want to add multiple kubeconfig: Add it like in `~/.bashrc` file

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/kubeconfig_dev.yml:~/.kube/kubeconfig_dev1.yml:~/.kube/kubeconfig_dev2.yml
```

with different Kube contexts and it worked well.

*Though the error should simplify and return the specific error related to kubecontext.*

But after some digging it worked.

Answer (score 2):

if u are running k3s u can put the following line to ur ~/.zshrc / ~/.bashrc

## k3s

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this! Just what the doctor ordered. 

Answer (score 1):

By default, kubectl looks for a file named config in the $HOME/. kube directory. So you have to rename your config file or set its location properly.

Look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) for more detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks, But as you can see above my contexts are in ~/.kube/ and I have multiple kubeconfig as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I used the Linux subsystem on Windows.
If you use the command `kubectl` in the subsystem, you must copy your config file to part of the Linux system.

For example, if your username on Windows is jammy, and your username is also jammy in the Linux subsystem, you must copy the config file
from:
/mnt/c/Users/jammy/.kube/config
to:
/home/jammy/.kube/